# what is Data Encipherment in a ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Can someone please point me to good articles on understanding the 'key usage' property of a ssl certificate? what are the pros and cons of getting a certificate issued with 'Data Encipherment' as one of the values?

Is this recommended? Recently we had to host a web service on our site, to be consumed by a third party and one of their requirements is that the certificate must have 'Data encipherment' in 'key usage'. Currently our site already has ssl, but key usage doesn't have 'data encipherment'.

Will there be any noticeable slowness if say we buy a new certificate with data encipherment and replace the current site certificate with the new one?

Answer (score 7):

You can read the spec, [RFC 5280 4.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3).  Basically Key Usage is just bits set on the certificate that restrict what the certificate authority certifies using the key for.  It should not affect SSL performance - I don't believe SSL even allows for Data Encipherment (using the public key to encrypt data versus using it to establish a symmetric key for data).